# OCaml type mismatch during compilation

Tags: ocaml, fold, type-mismatch

Look at my code:

```
let my lst p q =
  if lst = [] then
    []
  else
    let i = 0 in let res = [] in let acc=[] in
    fold_left ( fun acc h -> 
      if (not (p h) && not(q h)) then
    ((i+1), [], res)
      else if (p h && not (q h)) then
    ((i+1), (i::acc),res)
      else if (not (p h) &&  q h) then
    ((i+1), [] (acc@res))
      else
    ((i+1), [], ((i::acc)@res))) 
     (i,acc,res) lst;;
```

And I got error of compilation:

> This expression has type int * int list * 'a list
>          but an expression was expected of type int list

Can You help me ?

Comment: Which line does the compilation error refer to?

Comment: ((i+1), (i::acc),res)

Comment: I guess there is a typo there `(i+1), [] (acc@res))` a comma is missing

Answer (score 1):

The issue come from the way you use your fold function.

```
fold_left ( fun acc h -> 
  ...
)
```

In respect to your accumulator, which is a triple is better to do as follow,

```
 ....
fold_left ( fun (i', acc', res') h -> 
  here replace i, acc res by i' acc' res'
)
```

Furthermore remove the definition of i, acc, and res,.
Put directly their values like this,

```
 ....
fold_left ( fun (i', acc', res') h -> 
  here replace i, acc res by i' acc' res'
)  (0, [], []) lst;;
```

Finally the anonymous function call by `fold_left`,  should be bind upper the call of fold.

```
.....
let helper (i, acc, res) x = 
    .....
in fold_left helper (0, [], []) lst;;
```

Comment: np, a last note, try to evaluate `let lst = [] in List.fold_left (fun a x -> a*100 + x) 1 lst`.